# Can template variables be used as template parameters (similarly to class templates)?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, c++17

C++17 gives us the `auto` keyword for non-type template parameters. Is there a way to combine that to a template template parameter which can then be used with template variables as arguments?

```
template <template <typename> auto X> // <-- This seems to be illegal
struct Foo
{
};
```

Background:
I want to implement a copy_if for a type_vector class. Since all conditions I want to use are available as template variables, one way to implement it would be:

```
template <typename Container, 
          template <typename> auto Condition> // If this were allowed
struct copy_if;

template <typename... Ts,
          template <typename> auto Condition>
struct copy_if<type_vector<Ts...>, Condition>
{
  using type = decltype(
      (type_vector<>{} + ... + 
          std::conditional_t<Condition<Ts>, 
                             type_vector<Ts>,
                             type_vector<>>{}));
};
```

Of course, I could wrap all my variables into template structs that have a value, but I'd rather avoid that.

Comment: have you defined type_vector?

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes, `type_vector` is defined, same with `operator+` for concatenating two `type_vector`s

Comment: I don't know c++17 well enough but it seems to me that `template <typename> auto` makes no sense, because the auto can only possibly be a class. e.g. there is no concept of `template<typename> int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe additional predicate parameter (constexpr lambda available since c++17) establishing if parameter is conformed by your variable template would suffice?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
constexpr bool condition = true;

template <>
constexpr bool condition<int> = false;


template <class T>
struct tag { 
   using type = T;
};

template <class... Ts>
struct type_vector {
    template <class... Ts2>
    type_vector<Ts..., Ts2...> operator+(type_vector<Ts2...>);
};

template <class... Ts,
          class Predicate>
auto copy_if(type_vector<Ts...>, Predicate p)
{
  return decltype(
      (type_vector<>{} + ... + 
          std::conditional_t<p(tag<Ts>{}), 
                             type_vector<Ts>,
                             type_vector<>>{})){};
};

int main() {
    auto predicate = [](auto x){ return condition<typename decltype(x)::type>;};
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(copy_if(type_vector<int, float, double>{}, predicate))).name() << std::endl;
}
```

c++filt output:

```
type_vector<float, double>
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1Z4GwGzkbzVeX41E)

---

**Edit:**

There are situation when using artificial tag to dispatch parameter type might be perceived as cumbersome. If you would like to avoid it there is yet another way. This one actually avoids calling lambda's `operator()` templates it just instantiate it to evaluate result type (which should be equivalent of either `std::true_type` or `std::false_type`):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
constexpr bool condition = true;

template <>
constexpr bool condition<int> = false;

template <class... Ts>
struct type_vector {
    template <class... Ts2>
    type_vector<Ts..., Ts2...> operator+(type_vector<Ts2...>);
};

template <class... Ts,
          class Predicate>
auto copy_if(type_vector<Ts...>, Predicate p)
{
  return decltype(
      (type_vector<>{} + ... + 
          std::conditional_t<decltype(p(std::declval<Ts>())){}, 
                             type_vector<Ts>,
                             type_vector<>>{})){};
};

int main() {
    auto predicate = [](auto x){ return std::integral_constant<bool, condition<decltype(x)>>{};};
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(copy_if(type_vector<int, float, double>{}, predicate))).name() << std::endl;
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NefGdNx5NV2LaTc7)

Comment: Nice! I had thought about using a generic lambda but had not thought about the `tag` class. However, it means that whoever wants to use the `copy_if` has to deal with the `tag<T>` instead of T.

Comment: Yes it may be a little bit counterintuitive. I'll try to think a bit more about the approach, maybe something else will come to my mind.

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably end up writing a template class instead since that's easier to grok at the call site, but your second solution certainly is a good alternative.